# dropdown value post it to the controller php

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, controller

How can I set $cli with the value selected at dropdown?

**chartsController.php**

```
public function actionIndex()
{ 
   ...
 // Trae todos los datos del cliente seleccionado
    $cli = 1; //POST value de dropdown <<----<----

    $cli_sleccionado = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select('client_id, prod_id, order, survey_date')
    ->from('survey')
    ->where('client_id=:id',array(':id'=>$cli))
    ->orderBy( ['client_id'=>SORT_ASC, 'order' => SORT_DESC,])
    ->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
        'cli_sleccionado' => $cli_sleccionado,           
    ]);        

}
```

**index.php (view file)**

```
<div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                Id
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
               <?php 
                foreach($tot_cli as $key) {
                    echo '<li value="'.$key['client_id'].'"><a  href="#">'.$key['client_id'].'</a></li>';
                }

                ?>
            </ul>
            <i><b>...Por favor, selecciona un cliente. </b></i>
        </div>
```

[image]

I imagine it might be through Ajax, but I'm lost.

Comment: Are you happy for the page to be reloaded when an item is selected. Or do you want to use Ajax to pass the value to a PHP form, which then returns some content that you can place somewhere on your page?

Comment: Anything that works :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some ideas...

```
<form id="someForm" method="post" action="urlToPostTo">
    <input type="hidden" id="someValue" name="someValue">
</form>

<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then use some jquery

```
    $("#list li a").click(function(){ // Here we listen for a click on a link within the <li>
    var selectedValue = $(this).html(); // Put the value of the link into a variable

    // You could send this value to a PHP script using Ajax (in the background)
    $.post("some-script.php?id=" + selectedValue, function(response){
        // Place the response from the PHP script into an element
        $("#myElement").html(response);
    });

    // Or you can set the value of a hidden field in a form, and submit the form
    // This option will refresh your page
    $("#someValue").val(selectedValue);
    $("#someForm").submit();

    return false;
});
```

The idea with using Ajax would be that you submit the value to a PHP script, the PHP script grabs the data from the database and simply echo's some HTML content. This HTML content will be available in your jQuery via the 'repsonse' variable. You then set the HTML content of an element on your page to be the HTML generated by your PHP script (i.e. a table containing data)

Answer (score 0):

First I brought all the data through the controller

**chartsController.php**

```
// Array con todos los pedidos
    $surveys = \backend\models\Survey::find()->asArray()->orderBy(['order' => SORT_DESC,])->all();
```

**index.php (view)**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // **********ENVIO DE SELECCION DEL DROPDOWN**************** devuelve un array con los pedidos del cliente

      var surveys=<?php echo json_encode($surveys) ?> ;


      //Inicializo la funcion CON EL 1er cliente 
      var id_seleccionado = <?php echo $tot_cli[0]['client_id'] ?>; 
      var cliente = buscarCliente(id_seleccionado);
      cliente_cero (cliente); //llamo funcion cliente_cero

      function buscarCliente(idCliente){
          var pedidosCliente=[];
              for (s in surveys)
                  if (surveys[s].client_id==idCliente)
                     pedidosCliente.push(surveys[s]);

          return pedidosCliente;
       }

    //id_seleccionado se actualiza segun el id elegido
     function mostrarResultados(idCliente){
           cliente = buscarCliente(idCliente);
           cliente_cero (cliente);
           drawChart(); //dibujo google chart
     }

   //cargar el resto del array con 0, en el caso que contenga datos vacios
    function cliente_cero (cliente){
         while (cliente.length <5){
               cliente[cliente.length]= "";
         }
    }

     ...
   </script>
   <body>
   ...
   <!-- DROPDOWN-->
    <div class="dropdown" >
         <br><i><b>...Por favor, selecciona un cliente. </b></i>
         <select class="form-control" id="client" name="client" onChange="mostrarResultados(this.value);">
                 <?php
                  foreach($tot_cli as $key) {
                       echo '<option value="'.$key['client_id'].'">'.$key['client_id'].'</option>';
                  }
                  ?>
      </select>
   </div> <!--finDropDown -->
```

...